# Dumb TypeScript-ESLint issue: returning an unresolved Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have the following TypeScript code (dumbed down to demo the issue):

```
import * as argon2 from "argon2";

export default async function(password:string):Promise<string>
{
    return argon2.hash(password, {
        type: argon2.argon2id,
        memoryCost: 32768,
        parallelism: 4,
        timeCost: 12
    });
};
```

The goal is to apply custom parameters to the Argon2 hash method. The code presumably works fine, but my ESLint configuration is getting angry. Here's the relevant portion of my ESLint config:

```
        "require-await": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/require-await": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async": [
            "error",
            {
                "allowAny": false
            }
        ],
```

So long as the `async` keyword is present, this is tripping up the ["require-await" rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/require-await.md)

But when I remove the `async` keyword, this trips up the ["promise-function-async" rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md)

I'm not sure if:

- There's a smarter way to configure ESLint
- There's a smarter way to write the function that avoids these errors (maybe it's hinting at a legitimate potential bug that I'm just not seeing?)
- This is a valid case for `// eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: Those rules conflict, you can see that from their examples. Turn off one or the other. Or just `return await ...`.

Comment: Function `hash` is *async* (the return type is `Promise<>`)?

Comment: @VRoxa Yes, that's correct. The return type is specifically `Promise<string>`

Comment: Then, since you are not awaiting that Promise, you can get rid of the `async` keyword

Comment: @VRoxa The problem is that ESLint rule `@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async`, which states that any function returning a Promise should be listed as async. The reason for this rule is because a non-async Promise-returning function might throw an error instead of returning a Promise, triggering a synchronous catch block rather than triggering a Promise's `catch()` method. By adding `async` it causes the NodeJS runtime to ensure whatever is returned will be Promise-compatible, even if you `throw`

Answer (score 0):

You want to `return await argon2.hash(...)`.

```
export default async function(password: string) {
    return await argon2.hash(password, { /* ... */ });
};
```

- [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/require-await`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/require-await) enforces that if a function doesn't have an `await`, there's no need to make it `async`. This is good: the function doesn't need to have the extra overhead.
- [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/promise-function-async) enforces that if a Promise is a function, it should be marked as `async`. This is good: if a function returns a Promise but doesn't `await` anything, then the function won't show up in any `Error` stack traces.

[TypeScript playground showing a call stack skipping a function that returns a `Promise` but doesn't `await` it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBAMwK6wC4EsD2U4FsTpTACUcA3gFBxzjTzJpY4wBOApiKmwAoua7owbACoALTgCU2AKzYxUYEuSrUaAdwKo4vfoLYA6dmEwAbAG5sSAbhXVUovmrhQ2TgKIs+LYACIA8qLOmACEPsQ21AC+FCoM8kxw7KhILFBgOgJCYpIycgpKlKqJbMmpcKwcXBl62ahSsvKK4SrRKqgsEMpFIBroWkkpadVZ4nW5jdYt5ZwwgcBsnpgspIWqMNjGJgYmmADmvh5eAFw+ADRw84ssNGBwh0vE+mCoIDAA1s1RFJHE1kA). Note that if you click *Run*, the call stack has only  `createPromiseThatRejects` and `main`, "skipping" `returnsPromiseThatRejects()`.